# how to set redirect_uri in instagram basic display on a insecure protocol

Tags: php, laravel, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to follow [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started) to get the instagram user profile info and feed using laravel. There in no way for me to set the redirect_uri parameter on http://localhost:8000/callback_address. If i do that, i get the message:

```
{
    "error_type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 400,
    "error_message": "Invalid redirect_uri"
}
```

I tried to add it in the facebook developer console valid OAuth redirect URIs, but i get an error message which says that i should use HTTPS. I also tried to use socialite but i get the same error. The strange thing is that http redirect uri addresses are accepted for Facebook OAuth (by default, no need to write it in the developer console) but not for Instagram Basic Display.

This is the redirect statement which yelds the error above:

```
return redirect('https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={my-client-id}&redirect_uri=https://localhost:8000/login/instagrambasic/callback&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code')
```

I should use HTTP protocol in development, any idea? I've been stuck on this for a day, my eyes are bleeding.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to `urlencode()` the redirect URI. Try something like this:

```
$query_data = array(
    'client_id' => '{my-client-id}',
    'redirect_uri' => 'https://localhost:8000/login/instagrambasic/callback',
    'scope' => 'user_profile,user_media',
    'response_type' => 'code'
);

$url = sprintf('https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?%s', http_build_query($query_data);

return redirect($uri);
```

If you are using Socialite, this will be done for you, but make sure you use the [socialiteproviders/instagram-basic](https://packagist.org/packages/socialiteproviders/instagram-basic) package and not the older [socialiteproviders/instagram](https://packagist.org/packages/socialiteproviders/instagram) package, as this was for v1 of the API which is no longer supported.